# Is it correct to put 'to be' at the end of question?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, word-order, questions

For example, I could ask:

> How accurate is that answer?

But would it be correct to say:

> How accurate that answer is?

Comment: Note that _to be_ can very properly appear at the end of an interrogative: _"How accurate must my answer be?"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way is correct.

> How accurate is that answer?

The second way could be used as an exclamation but not as a question.

> How accurate that answer is!

Comment: I don't really think you mean *exclamation* here. It really doesn't rise much beyond *observation*.

Comment: @Robusto I did mean that. The `!` is an [exclamation mark](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/exclamation-mark-point). That is what elevates the sentence format beyond an observation, where it is clumsy.

Comment: ... an observation would be "That answer is accurate". My answer provides a usage as close as possible to the OP's second phrase.

Comment: The sentence may stand without an exclamation point. What I am saying is that adding one is not necessary, and is in fact rather ham-handed. You are presenting a false dichotomy here.

Comment: @Robusto I did not add an exclamation mark. I changed the existing question mark.

Comment: You went too far. As I said, a period would suffice.

Answer (score 7):

The first way is correct.

> How accurate is that answer?

The second way would be correct if it was a part of an indirect question. For example:

> Could you tell me how accurate that answer is?

One thing to note here is when to put a question mark. You see, when the first part of this complex sentence is not a question then you do not put a question mark at the end.

> I am wondering how accurate that answer is.

Or as Weather Vane said, it can be used as an exclamation, but then it is not a question:

> How accurate that answer is!

See more:
http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/indirect-questions.html

Comment: Nice answer (second quote). I considered converting the second thing asked by OP into a more complex question, in my answer, but you found it.